# difference between declaring protocols on public interface and private interface /implementation file

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is / are the differences between declaring these Protocols these ways? Is it just that the ones in the .h file are publicly available?

```
in .h file:
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

in .m file:
@interface TestViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Comment: This is a good question.  I normally declare them privately.  It's normally nobody's business who's delegate some class is, unless the caller plans to use it's instances as a delegate.

Comment: agreed that private makes sense but I mostly see them declared publicly and it's unclear to me why or whether there is a convention / reason for this that I'm not getting

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you add the protocols to the .h file, this tells everyone that includes the header file that the class adheres to the given protocols.

When you add the protocols to the .m file, this is essentially a private indication that the class adheres to the protocols. Only the implementation knows.

You should only use the first form (in the .h file) when outside classes need to know that the class adheres to the protocol. You should use the second form (in the .m file) when only the implementation cares.

In the example you gave, it is highly unlikely that other classes need to know about the class adhering to the table view protocols. Those should be in the .m file. It's also unlikely any other class needs to know about the search protocols. These are implementation details. These belong in the .m file.

There may be cases where you use both. This is fine.

Here' my guideline. Put it in the .m file unless you have a specific need to let other classes know about the use of the protocol.

Comment: `Put it in the .m file unless you have a specific need to let other classes know about the use of the protocol.` would the main need be overriding that method of the protocol?

Comment: The need to override a protocol method is one possible reason, not the main reason. You can override a protocol method even if the protocol is added in the .m file. The only caveat is that the overriding method can't call `[super protocolMethod]`. If you need to do this then the protocol must be added to the .h.

Comment: geez, this business is a bit of a mess; need to take shower and think through this.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I am mistaken, it is not possible to use the forward declaration `@protocol Foo;` if you are also declaring that your class is adopting the protocol.

Which means that in the header file of your class you need to include/import another header file with the protocol declaration. Depending on the size and complexity of a project, this can lead to header file "dependency hell".

Whether or not this is a real danger must be judged by the actual project. Most of the time it's probably not something you need to care about, but I just wanted to mention this angle.

Answer (score 3):

I admit it can not be matter of style!!!

Why to hide those protocols in .m, may be your classes will go with some frameworks. There .h is visible and everyone can see "Oh yaaa, these are the delegate protocols for this class". Instead of hidden magic.

So, it is made transparent rather than opaque.

Answer (score 1):

I judge preferable the first way, so that who uses the class knows if the class implements some protocol. This can only be an advantage.

Protocols are used to guarantee that some method are implemented, this is an alternative to multiple inheritance which isn't possible in Objective-C. Let's suppose that I want to pass an object that conforms to some protocol to a function or method, and I must be sure that this class implements some protocol. In this case *I must know which protocols the class is implementing*.

It also shuts up some compiler warning to functions (or methods) like these:

```
void foo(id< SomeProtocol> obj) {...}
```

Transparency is often a good idea and rarely a disadvantage.

Comment: so no technical difference at the objective c level? In general, I understand the idea of transparency but one could easily argue that part of OO programming is 'hiding the implementation' and this seems to be very much an implementation detail. Unless of course, it is meant to be overridden if you subclass. One issue is that protocols can have optional methods which makes the idea of transparency a little bit tricky. I am not saying any of this to disagree - I really don't know and just trying to learn.

Comment: The only two differences are that the user can see it and that it quiets some compiler warnings. As for the technical part at runtime it's all the same, and all these info will be lost.