# unrecognized selector from protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, protocols, arcgis

UPDATE: Issue found, solution found and marked as answer.

Issue is that I use a static method of the superclass to initialize, thus turning it into the superclass instead of subclass.

END UPDATE:

I have a protocol, a class that implements that protocol, and then a class that creates an instance of the protocol'd class that calls the protocol method. I am receiving an "Unrecognized selector sent to instance..." when invoking that protocol method.

Note: I am using ArcGIS for displaying a map, but that should be irrelevant to my problem.

The protocol method (`layerName`) works later during runtime on another object that implements LayerProtocol.

Example Code:

```
@protocol LayerProtocol <NSObject>
- (NSString *) layerName;
@end

@interface StreetLayer: AGSTiledMapServiceLayer<LayerProtocol>
@end

@implementation StreetLayer

- (id) init
{
    self = [AGSTiledMapServiceLayer tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:
            [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"%@%@",
                               @"https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/",
                               @"rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"]
             ]];
    return self;
}
- (NSString *) layerName
{
    return @"Street Layer";
}
@end

@interface MapContainerViewController: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) AGSMapView * mapView;
@property (nonatomic) StreetLayer * layer;
@end

@implementation MapContainerViewController
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    _mapView = [[AGSMapView alloc] init];
    _layer = [[StreetLayer alloc] init];
    [mapView addMapLayer:_layer withName:[_layer layerName]];
}
```

The error occurs on the access to `[_layer layerName]`

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here.

I do know that AGSLayer has an access to the name of the layer, that is irrelevant to the problem.

Additionally, I have used `[_layer respondsToSelector:@selector(layerName)]` and it fails that check.

STACK TRACE:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AGSTiledMapServiceLayer layerName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbe7ef90'

*** First throw call stack:
(

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x035105e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x032938b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x035ad903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0350090b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x035004ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   MyProject                            0x00061d95 -[MapContainerViewController mapTypeToggled:] + 677
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x032a5874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
7   UIKit                               0x01522c8c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
8   UIKit                               0x01522c18 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
9   UIKit                               0x0161a6d9 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
10  UIKit                               0x0161aa9c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
11  UIKit                               0x01619d4b -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
12  UIKit                               0x015600cd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
13  UIKit                               0x01560d34 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
14  UIKit                               0x01534a36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
15  UIKit                               0x0151ed9f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
16  CoreFoundation                      0x034998af __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0349923b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
18  CoreFoundation                      0x034b630e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
19  CoreFoundation                      0x034b5b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
20  CoreFoundation                      0x034b594b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
21  GraphicsServices                    0x051d49d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
22  GraphicsServices                    0x051d47fe GSEventRun + 104
23  UIKit                               0x0152194b UIApplicationMain + 1225
24  GmcSeeds                            0x00073b1d main + 141
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x03a7f725 start + 0
```

)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
- (void) mapTypeToggled:(id)sender
{
_streetViewToggled = !_streetViewToggled;
if (_streetViewToggled)
{
    // show street view
    [_mapView removeMapLayer:_satelliteLayer];
    [_mapView insertMapLayer:_streetLayer
                    withName:[_streetLayer layerName]
                     atIndex:0];
}
else
{
    // show satellite view
    [_mapView removeMapLayer:_streetLayer];
    [_mapView insertMapLayer:_satelliteLayer
                    withName:[_satelliteLayer layerName]
                     atIndex:0];
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please.

Comment: What class is receiving the "layerName" message?

Comment: Stack trace posted. I changed the project name and class name to match the question posted.

mapTypeToggled: is added to a button that hasn't been clicked yet.

Comment: Looks like the dynamic type of _layer is the base class type. What is the structure of your code? Are all these implemented in the same file? Any @synthesize macros used?

Comment: mapTypeToggled calls `[_layer layerName]`, but this is occurring when the screen is added to the view stack.

Comment: These are all in different files. I do not use @synthesize.

Comment: Does mapTypeToggled know the correct type of _layer? Can you add that method's code and context?

Comment: The exception error message ("AGSTiledMapServiceLayer layerName") suggests you are calling the base class, and not `StreetLayer` as you claim?

Comment: You don't seem to be calling layerName through delegate call but rather by direct call. Which explains the error.

Comment: LayerProtocol is in LayerProtocol.h.
The `@interface` for StreetLayer occurs in StreetLayer.h.
The `@implementation` for StreetLayer occurs in StreetLayer.m.
The `@interface` for MapContainerViewController occurs in the Map...Controller.h
The `@implementation` for Map...ViewController occurs in the Map...Controller.m

Comment: @trojanfoe

At no point in MapContainerViewController do I reference AGSTiledMapServiceLayer.

I just double checked.

Comment: Have you tried to place a breakpoint in `mapTypeToggled:` and see what type of object `_layer` actually is? Just use the `po` command on the variable name in the debugger's console.

Comment: Are you overriding the `alloc` or `init` methods for `StreetLayer`? Potentially you're breaking something along the line that is returning a base class object.

Comment: @Monolo I put a breakpoint at the first line. As I thought, it is never even called before the error is thrown.

Comment: @GuyKogus added the init method. I do use a static method for initializing, would that break it?

Comment: There is a standard pattern for `init` methods. Have you tried that one? Things will certainly change when you do. For the better.

Comment: @DrDisc: There you are. Your init method explicitly creates a AGSTiledMapServiceLayer object. It probably should be `self = [super tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL …]`. - It seems that Guy Kogus (and others ...) were on the right track.

Comment: @MartinR problem with that is that the `tiledMapService...` is a static method.

Comment: Your `init` method **does** use a class method...

Comment: @DrDisc: Can you rewrite tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL to a "normal" init method `initTiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:` and then call it as `self = [super initTiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:…` ? - Otherwise you will never get instances of the StreetLayer subclass.

Comment: You have to declare the method -(NSString *)layerName on your "StreetLayer.h". Then you can have access from other classes. Did you do this?

Comment: @MartinR I have no access to the AGS .m files. If someone posts an answer saying that I'm using a static method when I should be using a super method, I will mark it as the answer. Additionally, when I figure out the correct initialization, I will add it to the question/answer.

Comment: I think @scollaco has a valid suggestion --http://stackoverflow.com/a/14443394/2857130

Comment: @scollaco @staticVoidMan Problem with the suggestion is that it is essentially doing nothing new. The subclass declares it's following the protocols that declares `layerName`, but the static method in the init method is making it into a whole different class and not the right class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to replace this

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [AGSTiledMapServiceLayer tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:
            [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"%@%@",
                               @"https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/",
                               @"rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"]
             ]];
    return self;
}
```

with this

```
- (id) init
{
    self = [[self class] tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:
            [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"%@%@",
                               @"https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/",
                               @"rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"]
             ]];
    return self;
}
```

Better yet you should have a class method for creating a street layer:

```
@implementation StreetLayer

+ (instancetype)streetLayer
{
    return [[self class] tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:
                [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"%@%@",
                                   @"https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/",
                                   @"rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"]
                 ]];

}

@end
```

Comment: I like the use of the static method. I was thinking of making them singleton layers in the first place.

Comment: By the way, I implemented the static version and it works. The init version doesn't because the static method calls down to init and gets into an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, you can't implement both of them, it's one or the other :)

Comment: The init method won't work no matter what. It's calling down to init during `[[self class] tiledMapServiceLayerWithURL:]`

Comment: @DrDisc: there are no "static methods" in Objective-C. this is a *class method*

Comment: @GuyKogus: inside the class method, there is no point in doing `[self class]` -- it's exactly the same thing as `self`

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks, I kinda just copied it from the first example :)

Comment: Static vs class doesn't matter to my point. My point is that init will be called by the `tileMapServiceLayerWithURL` call and an infinite loop occurs.