# ios/xcode/objective-c: UIPickerView Not Displaying

Tags: ios, storyboard, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView that shows up in storyboard but is invisible or at best a colored block if I change the background color when I compile the program.  Do I need to populate it with data for it to display, i.e. does it no longer show Cupertino, Mountain View etc. once compiled?

BTW, I am trying to populate picker view with data but still invisible:

```
    code:
    in .h file:
@interface pickerVC : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *color;
    @property (strong, nonatomic)          NSArray *myArray;

    in viewdidload;
       UIPickerView *pickerView;
        pickerView.delegate = self;
        _myArray  = [[NSArray alloc]         initWithObjects:@"Blue",@"Green",@"Orange",@"Purple",@"Red",@"Yellow" , nil];


    //PICKER METHODS
    // tell the picker how many rows are available for a given component
    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
     //   NSUInteger numRows = 3;

        return _myArray.count;
    }

    // tell the picker how many components it will have
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
        return 1;
    }

    // tell the picker the title for a given component
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        NSString *title;

        title = _myArray[row];

        return title;
    }

    // tell the picker the width of each row for a given component
    - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        int sectionWidth = 300;

        return sectionWidth;
    }
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSLog(@"Selected Row %d", row);
    switch(row){
        // Handle the selection
    }
```

Comment: Please add some code here for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is not displaying. You have to set delegate and datasource of picker view and implement delegate methods in your controller.m file.
e.g.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 10;
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return @"ABC";
}
```

Comment: To set delegate and datasource do I have to drag from picker controller to something?

Comment: Ok got it to display by dragging from picker view to yellow icon in VC in storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you need to implement the data source and picker view delegates.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add this
 `<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>` in your .h file
after that add there Delegate Methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 5;
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return @"xyz";
}
```

Comment: Don't add the delegate methods in .m (implementation file), Instead add it in the header file. Here is a reference link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442698/difference-between-declaring-protocols-on-public-interface-and-private-interface